# Issues trying to check a couple of RSS feeds (from a JSON config file) in Node.JS (using rss-parser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rss

I'm currently trying to make a node.js script to read a couple of RSS feeds from a JSON file (`config.json`), check everyone and send new items to it's specific webhook for Discord.

The config file is the following:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "r/aww",
    "avatar": "https://example.com/avatar.jpg",
    "rss_url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/top/.rss",
    "webhook_url": "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/..."
  },
  {
    "name": "r/ImaginaryLandscapes",
    "avatar": "https://example.com/avatar.jpg",
    "rss_url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/ImaginaryLandscapes/top/.rss",
    "webhook_url": "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/..."
  }
]
```

And the code that i attempted to do, following sync examples from [rss-parser npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser), is the following:

```js
let Parser = require('rss-parser');

let parser = new Parser();

const config = require("./config.json");

config.forEach(element => {
    
    parser.parseURL(element.rss_url, function(err, feed) {
      console.log(feed);

      feed.items.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log(entry.title + ':' + entry.link);
      });
    });

});
```

But trying to run it throws the following error:

```
undefined
/mnt/d/misc/feedchecker/script.js:28
          feed.items.forEach(function(entry) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
    at /mnt/d/misc/feedchecker/script.js:28:9
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/mnt/d/misc/feedchecker/node_modules/rss-parser/lib/utils.js:63:29)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

What I'm doing wrong on this code? Please note that i still didn't wrote the webhook sending part, I'm focused still on fetching the feeds first.

Comment: Is anything being logged to console? My guess would be that there's a CORS issue accessing the feed. 

Cannot read items of undefined means the feed is undefined meaning access to it isn't happening.

Look at the npm doc and there's an example using CORS Anywhere.

Comment: @rachel in fact there is, but is an example to load the library in browser (client-side), not server-side as i want to do... strange.

About the console, i pasted everything that appeared when i tried to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this specific error was caused because i was (without knowing) using Node.JS v10 (that is the version that is shipped by apt by default for WSL's Ubuntu).

Reinstalling Node.JS using NodeSource repository gives me the version 16 that is able to run the code without issues.